# qt connect classes in different windows

Tags: c++, qt, class

I guess this is a bit of a beginner's QT question, so I hope you can give me a brief example how to solve my problem.

I have my login window:

```
#include "logint.h"
#include "ui_logint.h"

LoginT::LoginT(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::LoginT)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPixmap pix("C:/Users/Boushar/Desktop/Bachelor_Fred/Coden/UbbenLogoKlein.jpg");
    ui->label_pic->setPixmap(pix);

    if(!connOpen())
        ui->label->setText("Failed to open Database");
    else
        ui->label->setText("Connected.....");
}

LoginT::~LoginT()
{
    delete ui;
}

void LoginT::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);

    switch(e->type())
    {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui->retranslateUi(this);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void LoginT::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString username, password;
    username = ui->lineEdit_username->text();
    password = ui->lineEdit_password->text();

    if(!connOpen())
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open the database";
        return;
    }

    connOpen();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("select * from Worker where wo_login_name='" + username + "' and wo_password='" + password + "'");

    if(qry.exec())
    {
        int count = 0;

        while(qry.next())
            count++;

        if(count == 1)
        {
            ui->label->setText("username and password is correct");
            connClose();
            this->hide();
            WorkerT workert;
            workert.setModal(true);
            workert.exec();
        }

        if(count > 1)
            ui->label->setText("Duplicate username and password");

        if(count < 1)
            ui->label->setText("username and password is not correct");
    }
}
```

In my Login Window, I have to put in my user data (username and password), then I compare it with my database and get the user specific data back. so now my second window opens.

How can I manage that my second window gets the user information from the first window? I guess it's a really simple solution but I come from c++ programming and I would just commit it to my main.

I forgot to mention that I have a class for my user.

Comment: Got rid of 'test-speak' spellings which interrupt the flow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just make the main window take an `User`-Object in the constructor.

In your main window class the constructor should look like this:

```
MainWindow(QWidget* parent, User user);
```

After authentication show it like this:

```
auto w = new MainWindow(this, your_user);
w->show();
```

Comment: then i can use it from all my windows? can u give me a brief code example ?

Comment: @FrederikUbben I have added very small code examples. Hope it helps.